# Parsing a JSON Map to object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I'm converting my response that is in JSON to a readable form. The response is a Map.i.e it has a key and value.

```
 data={
  "name":"name1"
  "mapIWantToConvert":{
                       "key1":"value1"
                       "key2":"value2"
                       "key3":"value3"
                      }
      }
```

I want to iterate and get all the values of key and value and set them to other var.I am getting keys from a for loop.
this is not working:

```
var convertedData=data.mapIWantToConvert.key[i];
```

what am i doing wrong. thank you

output is a again a json file but a different one .

```
output={
    "allDataForkey1":{
                       "key1":"value1"
                      }
    "allDataForKey2":{
                      "key2":"value2"
                      }
 }
```

Comment: data2 = data.mapIWantToConvert ?

Comment: Could you provide some sort of expected output?

Comment: plz check the edited or updated question @taguenizy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the values from the convert the `mapIWantToConvert` key in the response you can do it like so.

```js
var data = {
  "name": "name1",
  "mapIWantToConvert": {
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2",
    "key3": "value3",
  }
}

var dataMap = data.mapIWantToConvert;

var values = Object.keys(dataMap).reduce(
  (valueArr, key) => [...valueArr, dataMap[key]], 
  []
)

console.log(values)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over an object's keys like this:

```
var myObject = data.mapIWantToConvert
var newObject = {}

for (var key in myObject) {
    if (myObject.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        newObject[key] = myObject[key]
    }
}
```